# LIsten for a click on a link even if it's inside of a div or img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use a click listener like this so that a click that goes to link.php will execute some code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {    
    var tre = e.target.href || '';
    if( tre.indexOf("link.php") > -1) {
        alert('it worked');
    }
}, false);
```

This works:

```
<a href="/link.php?destination=1" target="_blank">
    link text
</a>
```

But clicks on images or divs don't:

```
<a href="/link.php?destination=1" target="_blank">
    <img src="/image.jpg">
    <span>link text</span>
</a>
```

since clicks are on the image and span, not the `<a>` tag. What's the simplest way to make this work?

Comment: Since the span and img tags are wrapped inside the anchor tag, any click on those elements would trigger the event on anchor. Like this : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/cw96h622/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript does have a native [`.closest()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) (although it is currently considered experimental and has limited browser support). You can use this method in order to get the closest `a` ancestor element (or the element itself, which means that it would work in both of the cases that you provided).

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rbnbzhog/)

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {    
    var href = e.target.closest('a').href || '';
    if (href.indexOf("link.php") > -1) {
      // ...
    }
}, false);
```

Alternatively, you could check if each parent node is an `a` element:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/pynfkcL8/)

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target

  while (target && target.tagName !== 'A') {
    target = target.parentNode;
    if (!target) { return; }
  }

  if (target.href.indexOf("link.php") > -1) {
    // ...
  }
}, false);
```

Another option is to attach the event listener directly to the `a` element and then access the [`currentTarget` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) in order to get the element that the event was *attached* to (rather than the element that triggered the event). However, that would only attach the event to a single `a` element:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/a6rprq2p/)

```
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(e) {    
    var href = e.currentTarget.href || '';
    if (href.indexOf("link.php") > -1) {
      // ...
    }
}, false);
```